Is every $A:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ basically just a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
Pick an arbitrary linear operator $A:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. When one looks at the image of a rectangle (containing the origin) under this transformation, it looks as through it has been rotated in 3D space, projected back onto the $xy$-plans, and possibly scaled a bit. Even when $\det A < 0$, it just looks like it's been rotated more than $\pi$ radians, causing a "mirror" image. So I guess my question is best formulated as follows:

Claim: Define $P:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as the projection from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$. Given an arbitrary $A \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, then there exists a rotation matrix $R \in M_{3\times3}(\mathbb{R})$ --- i.e. $\det R = 1$ and $R^{-1} = R^{\intercal}$ --- and a scalar $s\in \mathbb{R}, s>0$ such that
$$
A = sPRP^{\intercal}
$$

Is there any hope of this being true? And if yes, then is there some way of generalizing this to linear operators in other dimensions? For example, is every linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$ basically just a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^4$? What about $\mathbb{R}^n$ compared to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

I suppose I should have specified that $A$ is not the zero operator.

I don't understand Ted's comment - a 2D reflection can come from a 3D rotation, and a projection or shear can come from a rotation around a 3D axis whose 2D projection is the desired transformation's eigenspace. The conjecture sounds plausible to me.

Right. A projection onto a 1D subspace would just be rotating the $xy$-plane "on its side" in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

@Ted Projections are easier. As an example,
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\0&0}
$$
is a submatrix of the rotation
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\0&0&1\0&-1&0}.
$$

Sorry. I missed the important issue.

The answer is yes!
Note that for a given matrix $sR$, $A = P(sR)P^\top$ is its upper left submatrix. So, your question can be reframed as follows: given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, can we take the partial matrix
$$
\mathcal A = \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} & ?\\a_{21} & a_{22} & ?\\
?&?&?}
$$
and fill in the entries such that we end up with a multiple of a rotation? In other words, can we fill in the $?$ in such a way that the result has

rows of the same length (i.e. same magnitude),
orthogonal rows,
positive determinant?

(Equivalently, you could impose these conditions on the columns of $\mathcal A$).
Imposing condition 1 leads to the equation
$$
a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 + a_{13}^2 = a_{21}^2 + a_{22}^2 + a_{23}^2 \implies\\
a_{13}^2 - a_{23}^2 = a_{21}^2 + a_{22}^2 - a_{11}^2 - a_{12}^2 := c_1
$$
Imposing condition 2 leads to the equation
$$
a_{11}a_{21} + a_{12}a_{22} + a_{13}a_{23} = 0\implies\\
a_{13}a_{23} = -(a_{11}a_{21} + a_{12}a_{22}) := c_2\\
$$
If we regard these equations as describing graphs over $x = a_{13}$ and $y = a_{23}$, then the above equations describe (possibly degenerate) hyperbolas. In non-degenerate cases, the asymptotes of $x^2 - y^2 = c_1$ are $y = \pm x$, and the asymptotes of $xy = c_2$  are the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Claim: These graphs intersect

Proof: Fist, in the case that $c_2 = 0$, it suffices to take $y = 0$ if $c_1\geq 0$ is positive and $x = 0$ if $c_1 \leq 0$.
Otherwise, solve the second equation for $y$ to get $y = c_2/x$. Plug into the first equation to get
$$
x^2 - (c_2/x)^2 = c_1 \implies\\
x^4 - c_1 x^2 - c_2^2 = 0 \implies\\
z^2 - c_1z - c_2^2 = 0.
$$
We have a monic quadratic over $z:= x^2$ with a negative constant term, which means that this quadratic is guaranteed to have a positive and negative root. Setting $x^2$ equal to the positive root gives our solution.
$$
x^2 = \frac{c_1 + \sqrt{c_1^2 + 4c_2^2}}{2} \implies
x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{c_1 + \sqrt{c_1^2 + 4c_2^2}}{2}},
$$
and plugging into $y = c_2/x$ gives us $y$. $\qquad \square$
Now, once you have values for $a_{13}$ and $a_{23}$ satisfying the system of equations described above, you have two rows of the desired scaled rotation $sR$ that are of the same length and mutually orthogonal.
From there, you can simply use a cross-product and scale to get the third row. That is, take
$$
(a_{31}, a_{32}, a_{33}) = 
\frac{(a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}) \times (a_{21}, a_{22}, a_{23})}{\sqrt{a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 + a_{13}^2}}.
$$
The resulting filled in matrix is such that dividing by $\sqrt{a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 + a_{13}^2}$ yields a rotation matrix.

Here's a quick Python script to implement the steps from my answer.
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import det, norm

# fill in "A" matrix here
A = np.array([
    [1,1],
    [0,1]
    ])


c1 = A[1,0]**2 + A[1,1]**2 - A[0,0]**2 - A[0,1]**2
c2 = -(A[0,0]*A[0,1] + A[1,0]*A[1,1])

# fill in first two rows
a02 = np.sqrt((c1 + np.sqrt(c1**2 + 4*c2**2))/2)
a12 = c2/a02

# get the final row
u = np.array([*A[0], a02])
v = np.array([*A[1], a12])
w = np.cross(u,v)/norm(u)


# build the matrix sR
B = np.vstack([u,v,w])

# get s and R
s = norm(u)
R = B/s

print(f"s = {s:.5f}")
print("R = ")
print(R.round(5))
print()



# test orthogonality: should print out an identity matrix
print("R R^T:")
print((R@R.T).round(10))
print()

# test that orthogonal matrix is a rotation:
# should print a determinant of 1
print(f"det(R) = {det(R)}")

Resulting output:
s = 1.61803
R = 
[[ 0.61803  0.61803  0.48587]
 [ 0.       0.61803 -0.78615]
 [-0.78615  0.48587  0.38197]]

R R^T:
[[ 1. -0. -0.]
 [-0.  1.  0.]
 [-0.  0.  1.]]

det(R) = 0.9999999999999998


An interesting generalization: given $n$, what is the smallest $m$ such that for the analogous "projection" $P:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, every $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times m}$ can be expressed in the form $sPRP^T$ for a suitable rotation $R$?
I believe we can come up with an upper bound to $m$ with the help of dimension counting. It is known that $SO(n)$ forms a manifold of dimension $n(n-1)/2$. So, the matrices of the form $sR$ for some $s > 0$ and $R \in SO(n)$ form a manifold of dimension $1 + n(n-1)/2$.
I suspect that the image of this manifold under the smooth map $X \mapsto PXP^T$ occupies a "subspace" of $\Bbb R^{m \times m}$ that has dimension at most $1 + n(n-1)/2$.  So, in order for this map to be onto, we must have
$$
m^2 \leq 1 + n(n-1)/2  \implies\\
m \leq \sqrt{\frac{n^2 - n + 2}{2}}.
$$

Wow! That's pretty slick!! Meant thanks. Do you have any sense about the more generalized problem I posed?

@Patch Feels like it should be true but I can't say so with any certainty.

I'll accept this answer tomorrow. I'd like to leave it open for just a little while longer in case someone has something to say about the general case. Thanks again, though.

@Patch actually, I can definitively say that the general statement is not true as given. In general, a matrix $A$ attained in this fashion will necessarily have a rank of at least $n-1$. So for instance, we can't find a suitable $R$ for
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\0&0&0\0&0&0}.
$$

@Patch I have no idea whether this rank-condition is sufficient to guarantee a suitable $R$, though. I'm now inclined to think "probably not"

Hmmm. Fascinating. Thanks for the feedback. I'll accept this answer now.

@Patch I added some more that you might find interesting.

There's another approach that one could take using the singular value interlacing theorem that I believe actually characterizes which matrices $A$ can be extended into a rotation. Notably, for rotations (like all orthogonal matrices), the singular values are all equal.

Nice argument! A slightly tighter demonstration of the claim in the answer would be that $x$ and $y$ can be taken as the real and imaginary parts of a square root of $c_1 + 2 i c_2$.

@Damian I knew I was missing a slicker approach! That's an excellent find.

In general, let $P=\pmatrix{I_n&0}\in M_{n,N}(\mathbb R)$ for some $n<N$. You are asking whether there exist some $s>0$ and $R\in SO(N)$ such that the leading principal $n\times n$ submatrix of $R$ is $B=sA$.
Let $R=\pmatrix{B&Y\\ Z&W}$. For $R$ to be orthogonal, we need $R^TR=I_N$. In particular, $B^TB+Z^TZ=I_n$ with $\|B\|_2\le1$. Since $Z$ is $(N-n)\times n$, we have $N-n\ge\operatorname{rank}(Z)=\operatorname{rank}(Z^TZ)=\operatorname{rank}(I_n-B^TB)$. In turn, the nullity of $I_n-B^TB$ is at least $2n-N$. Hence $R$ exists only if $\|B\|_2\le1$ and at least $2n-N$ singular values of $B$ are equal to $1$ (note: when $B=0$, this means $0\ge 2n-N$), i.e., only if the largest nonzero singular value of $A$ has multiplicity $k\ge 2n-N$ (where $k$ is taken to be zero if $A=0$).
This condition is also sufficient. Let $B=\frac{A}{\|A\|_2}$ if $A\ne0$ and $B=0$ otherwise. Then $B$ has a singular value decomposition $U\pmatrix{I_k\\ &D}V^T$ where $\|D\|_2<1$ (and $I_k$ is empty if $k=0$, $D$ is empty if $k=n$). Hence the matrix $R$ given by
$$
\pmatrix{U\\ &I_{N-n}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
I_k&0&0&0\\ 0&D&-\sqrt{I_{n-k}-D^2}&0\\
\hline
0&\sqrt{I_{n-k}-D^2}&D&0\\ 0&0&0&I_{k-(2n-N)}\\
\end{array}
\right]
\pmatrix{V^T\\ &I_{N-n-1}\\ &&\det(UV)}
$$
is a member of $SO(N)$ whose leading principal $n\times n$ submatrix is $B=sA$ where $s=\frac{1}{\|A\|_2}A$ if $A\ne0$ and $s=1$ otherwise.

What exactly is your $||A||_2$ norm on a matrix?

@Patch $|A|_2$ is a popular, if not standard, notation for the induced $2$-norm of $A$, i.e., $|A|2=$ the largest singular value of $A$ = $\max{|x|_2=1}|Ax|_2$.

It seems so obvious once you wrote it out, nicely done

Thanks! One question though. Your final conclusion is that "the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of $Q$ in this case is $N \geq 2n$. But in my initial example we have $n = 2$ and $N=3$, which doesn't follow your conclusion. What is it that I'm missing?

@Patch Nothing is missing. If $n=2,N=3$ and $A=0$, the desired $Q$ (or in your notation, $R$) does not exist. This is evident: if the leading principal $2\times2$ submatrix of $Q$ is zero, the rank of $Q$ is at most $2$ and hence it cannot possibly be an orthogonal matrix.

But didn't @BenGrossmann explicitly demonstrate that such an R (you call it Q) does exist? He build up the equations for R in his version of the answer, and it is indeed a rotation. What am I misunderstanding about your conclusion, because it would seem to me that you've established that as long as $A\neq 0$ then such a rotation matrix $Q$ cannot "encode" the transformation of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ unless $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{4\times4}$.

@Patch What is $\frac{(a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}) \times (a_{21}, a_{22}, a_{23})}{\sqrt{a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 + a_{13}^2}}$ when $a_{11}=a_{12}=a_{21}=a_{22}=0$?

I see, now, that your proof is broken up into two cases: one where $A\neq 0$ and one where $A=0$. And yes, that would make total sense to me that you would need to rotate the 2D plane inside of $\mathbb{R}^4$ in order to achieve the zero transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So please just confirm for me that I have the proper understanding of your conclusion from the non-zero case: A scaled-rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ encodes a nonzero $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ if and only if the largest singular value of $A$ has multiplicity $k \geq 2n-N$.

@Patch Yes. And I have edited my answer to merge the two cases $A\ne0$ and $A=0$. Now $k$ is defined to be the multiplicity of the largest nonzero singular value of $A$. It is taken to be zero if $A=0$.

Very nice. Thank you, again, for sharing.
